# Finding the equation of a line that is tangent to.

Tags: tangent-line

I have the following question & its answer but I do not understand how some parts were obtained - [Q&A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVPQV.png), [Previous Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdbD0.png)

Where does the $1+dy/dx (x-1)$ come from?

Comment: Please study [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), and improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so you don't have any problem with calculating $\frac{dy}{dx}$

you want to find the tangent at the curve at the point (1,1)

the equation of a line passing through the point (1,1) is given by

$$(y-1)=m(x-1)$$
where m is the slope of the line

now to calculate$$ m=slope=\frac{dy}{dx}\big|_{(1,1)}$$
$$ m=slope=-\frac{2x+y}{x+y}\big|_{(1,1)}$$
$$ m=slope=-\frac{2(1)+(1)}{(1)+(1)}=\frac{-3}{2}$$

thus equation of tangent $$(y-1)=-\frac{3}{2}(x-1)$$
                         $$y-1=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$y=-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense, that’s exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming $y=y(x)$ then we get by the chain and product rule

$4x+2y(x)y'(x)+2y(x)+2xy'(x)=0$
Can you finish?

Comment: I've already worked that out to be $-2x+y/x+y$ that's where I apply the bottom bit and get $-(3/2)$ I don't get where the $(x-1)$ comes from.